# How to Add Document Class to AucTeX

Tags: latex, auctex

I have a `.cls` LaTex template I would like to use regularly. Where/how should I save it so that AucTeX is aware of it? How does one set up LaTeX templates in Emacs/Spacemacs in general? I find very few resources specific to Emacs that do not require Org-mode.

Comment: The first question is not really AUCTeX specific. The question and answers here should be helpful https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te